# How to charge a capacitor using a push button?

Tags: capacitor, digital-logic

I am trying to create a single-click logic detector that will hold a voltage of 1 for any single button click made. [image]

If a button press is made, the SR FF will activate, charging the capacitor to 5V since the BJT is also forward biased and the capacitor will be able to charge through the 3.5K resistor.

I need this capacitor to hold a value of 1 for a single button press however, the moment that Q becomes 0, the charge in the capacitor will also forward bias the NPN BJT and discharge itself through the 3.5K resistor. How can I achieve this?

I also plan to add another push button later that will forward bias the BJT so that it will be the ONLY way to discharge the capacitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the top of the capacitor to +5 V (not Q)

Move the 3.5 k (why do you have that value ?) to the collector of the NPN

Insert 10k between Q and the base of the NPN.

When S (or R) are open circuit, the logic value is not defined. Put a 10k to GND on each of those.

Now, S and R will operate as you expect (you could now use simpler pushbuttons -- you don't need the pairs of terminals connected to GND).

When Q goes high, the NPN will turn on and charge (quite slowly) the 220 mF (it will take ~ 3*R.C = 3*3k*220m = 2000s, or over 30 minutes).

It will remain charged that way, even if a load is connected

If you then press the button on R, the NPN will turn off; the capacitor will remain charged until a load is connected to it.

Comment: OHHH, instead of latching both capacitor and npn, only the npn is latched so that the push button only acts to forward bias the npn. My only problem now is to chose a capcitor and resistors that will charge the cap to 5V upon a 1 second press. I'll compute that later on . Thank You

Comment: 220 mF (that's a huge capacitor, and is not generally available with a 5 V rating) would require about 25 A to charge to 5 V in 1 s. Perhaps you mean 220 uF (microfarad) -- that would require 25 mA, so use 47 Ω in the collector (not 3.5k), and use 470 Ω in the base (not 10 k)